# Compute $h^{(r)}(x_0)$, $r=1,2,3,4$, given that $h(x)=e^x \sin(x)$, about $x_0 = 0$

Tags: real-analysis

> Compute $h^{(r)}(x_0)$, $r=1,2,3,4$, given that $h(x)=e^x \sin(x)$, about $x_0 = 0$

let $h = fg$ with $f(x)=e^x$ and $g(x)=\sin x$

Using Leibniz's rule,
$$(fg)^{n}(x_0) = \sum_{k=0}^{n} \frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!} f^{(k)}(x_0) g^{(n-k)}(x_0)
$$
$$(fg)^4(0)=\frac{0!}{0!(0)!} f^{(0)}(0) g^{(0)}(0)+\frac{1!}{0!(1)!} f^{(0)}(0) g^{(1)}(0)+\frac{2!}{0!(2)!} f^{(0)}(0) g^{(2)}(0)+\frac{3!}{0!(3)!} f^{(0)}(0) g^{(3)}(0)+\frac{4!}{0!(4)!} f^{(0)}(0) g^{(4)}(0)$$

$$(fg)^4(0)= e^0 \sin(0)+ e^0 \cos(0)+ e^0 (-\sin(0))+ e^0 (-\cos(0))+ e^0 sin(0)$$
$$(fg)^4(0)= 1 \cdot 0 + 1 \cdot 1 + 1 \cdot (-0)+ 1 \cdot (-1)+ 1 \cdot 0$$

$$(fg)^4(0)= 0$$

I am unsure about my expansion of the summation notation. Am i doing this correctly?

What would an alternative method of Leibniz formula be ?

Comment: Why not just compute the derivatives straight out to check?

Comment: If "passing by the complex plane" is allowed, one can use$$\sin x=\Im e^{ix}$$ hence  $$f(x)=\Im\left( e^{(1+i)x}\right)=\sum_{n=0}^4\Im\left((1+i)^n\right)\frac{x^n}{n!}+o(x^4)$$ and identify $$\Im(1+i)^0=\Im(1+i)^4=0\qquad\Im(1+i)^1=1\qquad\Im(1+i)^2=\Im(1+i)^3=2$$

Comment: You forgot the binomial factors in your final expression for $(fg)^{(4)}$.

Answer (score 1):

*This is more a comment than an answer.*

For this kind of problem, I think that using Taylor expansions is very useful

$$e^x=1+x+\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{x^3}{6}+\frac{x^4}{24}+\frac{x^5}{120}+\frac{x^6}{720}+O\left(x^7\right)$$
$$\sin(x)=x-\frac{x^3}{6}+\frac{x^5}{120}+O\left(x^7\right)$$ $$e^x \sin(x)=x+x^2+\frac{x^3}{3}-\frac{x^5}{30}-\frac{x^6}{90}+O\left(x^7\right)$$ Now, multiply the coefficients by the factorials to get the derivatives or just differentiate the last expansion.

Comment: "using Taylor expansions is very useful" ...Especially if one takes care to write down only the relevant terms, which, in the present case, are simply $$e^x=1+x+\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{x^3}{6}+\frac{x^4}{24}+o\left(x^4\right)$$ and
$$\sin(x)=x-\frac{x^3}{6}+o\left(x^4\right)$$

Comment: @Did. I just wanted to show that higher derivatives could be obtained easily.

Comment: And, as already explained, I think that providing expansions more complete than is necessary, and *with no explanations*, can be misleading.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici So you differentiate only $\sin e^x =x + x^2 + \frac{x^3}{3}$. And you differentiate 4 times. It ends up to be 0 . Correct?

Comment: @gegu. Since the derivatives at a given point are related to the coefficients of Taylor expansions, in your specific case, we need to  differentiate $x+x^2+\frac{1}{3} x^3+0 x^4$. Then the required results.